# Code Coverage Error in Rational Application Developer: "Must specify a URL scheme"

Tags: websphere, rad, ibm-rational

IBM Rational Application Developer For WebSphere Software
Version 9.6.1.1
Build ID: RADO9611-I20180321_1710

I have a problem seeing code coverage report in IBM RAD after enabled "code coverage" in the project properties. After running my app in the browser, the "code coverage panel workspace results" did not show the report for the active project. Instead, it displays Must specify a URI scheme; Project: MyProjectName.

The popup box says 'Generating workbench report for MyProjectName' has encountered a problem. Report not generated, Please see log for additional details. Must specify a URL scheme.

However, I did not see anything related to code coverage in the server log at all.

Welcome all advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research , it appears that “Enable filter customization” option has to be checked in the “Server Filter Set” panel. Otherwise, one will see “Must specify a URL scheme” issue.